# Excluding Intelij .iml files on multi-computer workspace

Tags: git, intellij-idea

As far as my understanding goes, the best practice is not to add IDE specific files like *.iml to git.

If a structural project / module change has occurred within one branch, can a Intellij project be corrupted when switching branches within the same project with untracked .iml files? New .iml files would be kept, that no longer represent the structure of another branch.

A similar issue might be: Refactoring a project on one workstation, then switching to a different computer and pulling changes from git would lead to a corrupt Intellij project, because the local .iml files no longer represent a project that has been structurally refactored.

Is it hazardous to not include .iml files in your SCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

In general, it is recommended to store *.iml files under VCS, not sure where the information about the "best practice is not to add IDE specific files like *.iml to git" comes from.

Comment: It's from the mantra 'Don't put IDE specific files in version control, as there are various IDEs out there and this kind of meta data would pollute the codebase'

Comment: From your source: 'You may consider not to share the following:

.iml files and .idea/modules.xml file for the Gradle or Maven based projects, since these files will be generated on import' - This means, as far as I understand, that structural changes without reimporting will destroy the project in Intellij

Comment: Yes, reimport is needed in case some changes are applied to e.g pom.xml to reflect them in IDE.

Comment: thank you for your answers. on a last note, would 'invalidate caches and restart' solve this issue if it occured? I would guess yes, but I'm not sure. Thanks again : )

Comment: If something is still wrong after project reimport (e.g. can't navigate to some classes, references not resolved, etc), Invalidating caches should help. But usually, reimport is enough and does not corrupt anything.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse was MUCH easier to corrupt a workspace than Intellij.  But it is a better practice to not commit anything under .idea to VCS.  There are a few places, especially workspace.xml where you can mess up other users.

Comment: It is recommended to exclude such files (especially workspace.xml) from VCS, while committing all other project configuration files. See the link in my reply